# What to do when my question is unanswerable

Tags: discussion, support

I posted a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459182/less-aggressive-synonym-for-left-the-company) with a [single-word-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request), and although I got multiple answers, it became clear that no such word exists.
Now, I'm unsure what to do with my question. Do I pick the answer that gets the closest to what I want, even if it's not a single word? Or do I just delete the question?

This question differs from the reported duplicate, in that this question is addressing the topic from the perspective of the OP (asker) rather than a contributor who is answering.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this meta question because the purported dupe is looking for something different. [Mr Hen's question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4349/142322) asks about 'no answer' SWRs from the community's perspective. Nils' question is asked from the OP's perspective.

Comment: The question linked is itself a duplicate of [What is the best way to answer a question which has no answer?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11196/what-is-the-best-way-to-answer-a-question-which-has-no-answer) And it seems to deal with the present topic sufficiently well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, I’d prefer if that question were used as the canonical for dupe purposes. If a diamond mod is reading this, can you please reopen and close this question as a dupe of Mari-Lou’s link, rather than the current dupe target?